# Prevent content from hiding behind fixed position navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar with 40px height and I can't place my other content (just a textarea) below this bar. I tried to set `margin-top:40px;` to the textarea but it doesn' t work.

Then I used `padding-top:40px` which is ok for the content inside the textarea but as you will see has a problem with the scrollbar (it gets behind the bar).

Just take a look at this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Y63u/1/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `padding-bottom: 40px` to the nav, and remove it from the text-area.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
postion:fixed;
and margin to push contents out
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Y63u/3/

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to **@Andrw Ice**'s answer

You just have to give the `textarea`s margin something to push against.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/4Y63u/14/)

This is common...as the advantage is that it doesn't cause any of the elements to moveif the navbar is hidden.

```
body {
    border:1px solid transparent;
}

nav + textarea{
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the padding from the textarea :P.